# Zero-padding of MFCC coefficients

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition, mfcc

I am trying to implement speech recognition using backpropagation algorithm, and I have been following [this paper](http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume42/number12/pxc3877946.pdf).
I have followed it all the way, except that it tells me to zero-pad the coefficients when there is an empty slot, because the MFCC coefficients of two samples are not the same.

Now my question is, do I randomly distribute the zeros through the coefficients, or is there a  rule of some type?

P.S- I have perused [this paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932096/matching-two-series-of-mfcc-coefficients) as well; however, the question does not relate to taking the MFCC coefficients an inputs.

Comment: Any solution guys .

Comment: MFCC coefficients are not the same but the number should be the same. If you randomly put zeros, then you change what they represented previously. If you pad zero, such that you put zeros "at the end", then this will not affect MFCC at all meaning If you transformed back from MFCC to frequency, those zeros wouldn't affect the result.